# How to convert `null` to a nullable int? I always get 0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

For reasons I won't bore you with, I have a generic object whose value is `null`, and I need to convert it to a nullable int.

```
object foo = null
int? bar = Convert.ToInt32(foo) // bar = 0
int? bar = (int?)Convert.ToInt32(foo) // bar = 0
int? bar = Convert.ToInt32?(foo) // not a thing
```

From [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18020146/convert-int-to-nullable-int):

```
int? bar = Expression.Constant(foo, typeof(int?)); // Can not convert System.Linq.Expression.Constant to int?
```

I need `bar` to be `null`.  How do I do this?

Comment: `int? bar = (int?)foo;` seems to work for me.

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32()` always returns an `int`, never a `null`. That seems to be the main flaw in your original attempts. If you go to an apple tree, you will **always** get an apple - never an orange.

Comment: I personally would suggest `int? bar = foo as int?;` This is slightly safer than using `(int?)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Better way to cast object to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/745172/better-way-to-cast-object-to-int)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will work

`int? bar = (int?)foo;`

However as pointed out in comments this will throw a `Specified cast is not valid` exception if `foo` is anything but a `null` or an `int`.

If you prefer just to get a `null` if the conversion is not valid then you can use

`int? bar = foo as int?;`

which will hide conversion problems.

Comment: Beat me to it by seconds.

Comment: Great minds think alike! 

Or is it fools seldom differ :D

Comment: well now I feel silly.  Trying to make things harder than they need to be, I guess

Comment: Hold on... :) What if foo is a string? It's typed as `object`, so it has no obligation to be convertible to an `int?`.

Comment: For sure you will get a runtime error if `foo` is anything but `null` or an `int`... but all the question asks for is to convert an `object null` to an `int? null`.

Comment: What @Loofer said and it might actually be desirable to get a runtime error in that instance where you're expecting an int instead of blindly hiding the error/bug. Obviously circumstance-dependent.